# How to block a user in group using QuickBlox Ios framework 2.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

I am using the following `code` to block group user but it gives me `error`.

Following is my logic of maintaining `QBPrivacyList` to block it but I didn't got succeed with it.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{ 
    [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];

    [[QBChat instance] retrievePrivacyListWithName:@"group_public"];
}

- (void)chatDidReceivePrivacyList:(QBPrivacyList *)privacyList{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    blockPrivacyList = privacyList;

    [[QBChat instance] setActivePrivacyListWithName:blockPrivacyList.name];
}

-(IBAction)blockGroupUser{

    QBPrivacyItem *item = [[QBPrivacyItem alloc] initWithType:GROUP valueForType:user.ID action:DENY];

    if (blockPrivacyList) {
        [blockPrivacyList addObject:item]; // add new user if already privacy list is there
    }else
        blockPrivacyList= [[QBPrivacyList alloc] initWithName:@"group_public" items:@[item]];
    }

    [[QBChat instance] setPrivacyList:blockPrivacyList];
}
```

Got following Error:

`<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="9C79DCE1-AC59-4C9D-8AB2-BE2387B1EED4" to="5554981-24659@chat.quickblox.com/D060E713-F1DC-46D7-A2BF-8DA7BDB22CBA" type="error"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"><list name="group_public"><item action="deny" order="5291124" value="5291124-24659@chat.quickblox.com" type="group"><iq/><message/><presence-in/><presence-out/></item></list></query><error type="cancel" code="404"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate your privacy list after editing it

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Activate_a_privacy_list

```
-(IBAction)blockGroupUser{

    QBPrivacyItem *item = [[QBPrivacyItem alloc] initWithType:GROUP valueForType:user.ID action:DENY];

    if (blockPrivacyList) {
        [blockPrivacyList addObject:item]; // add new user if already privacy list is there
    }else
        blockPrivacyList= [[QBPrivacyList alloc] initWithName:@"group_public" items:@[item]];
}

    [[QBChat instance] setPrivacyList:blockPrivacyList];
}

- (void)chatDidSetPrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name{
    [[QBChat instance] setDefaultPrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
    [[QBChat instance] setActivePrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
}

- (void)chatDidSetDefaultPrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name{

}

- (void)chatDidNotSetDefaultPrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name error:(id)error{

}

- (void)chatDidSetActivePrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name{

}

- (void)chatDidNotSetActivePrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name error:  (id)error{

}
```